# Android - get item tag/name value of a spinner component

Tags: android, tags, spinner, selecteditem

I am developing an android application in which I've used a spinner to populate 3 values (+, -, +/-) which are stored in the backend as (Plus, Minus, PlusMinus) in an enum variable.

"strings.xml" looks like this

```
<string-array name="alert_variation">
    <item tag="Minus">+</item>
    <item tag="Plus">-</item>
    <item tag="PlusMinus">+/-</item>
</string-array>
```

'Spinner' component looks like this

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/alert_variation_spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:entries="@array/alert_variation"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

When the spinner value changes, how can I get the selected tag value (Plus, Minus, PlusMinus) instead of (+,-,+/-) value in my Activity.java file? I can even use `<item name=""></>` if needed.

The code to get the +,-,+/- value is

```
"alertVariationType.getSelectedItem().toString()"
```

but instead I would like to get the 'tag' or 'name' value. Can someone please suggest me the solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Android Studio available to me right now, so I apologize for not being able to independently validate this, but have you tried this?

```
alertVariationType.getSelectedItem().getTag().toString()
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response. But unfortunately there isn't anything available like that.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution to this problem - create an arrayadapter from a custom object.Here's how:

```
public class Signs {

String name,sign;

public Signs(String name, String sign)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.sign=sign;
}

public String toString()
{
    return sign;
}
}
```

And use it like so in the spinner, The output string sign will be plus/minus etc:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

 ArrayAdapter<Signs> signs = new ArrayAdapter<Signs>   (this,
 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new Signs[]{new Signs("Plus","+"),
 new Signs("Minus","-"), new Signs("PlusMinus","+/-")});

    spinner.setAdapter(signs);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String sign =   ((Signs)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).name;

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Varsha, thank you for your clear response. Let me check it and get back to you if I've any doubts.